# Set-ADGroup : An invalid dn syntax has been specified

Tags: powershell, active-directory

```
Set-ADGroup -Identity "St.Department.146" -Replace @{"msExchRequireAuthToSendTo"=$true} -verbose
```

An error occurs when entering a command. :(

Set-ADGroup : An invalid dn syntax has been specified At line:1 char:1

- Set-ADGroup $InternalDistro -Replace @{msExchRequireAuthToSendTo = $T ... + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
- CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (CN=St.Departmen...ublethink,DC=me:ADGroup) [Set-ADGroup], ArgumentExce
  ption

  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Comm
    ands.SetADGroup

Comment: Please add any error messages you're seeing. "An error occurred" doesn't really help.

Comment: I couldn’t replicate the issue. Is your hash table on the same line as -add?

Comment: Yes it is on the same line.

Comment: Your error shows -replace but your posted command shows -add.

Comment: Also your posted command contains a CN or rather the SAMAccountName, while exception reports seeing a full DN wrapped in parentheses. Something is fishy around your infrastructure, I say you need to trace your variables, probably you change the object type assigned to a var somewhere.

Comment: @DougMaurer Thanks for the help.The problem is the same with -replace

Comment: @Vesper Thanks for the help. Is the variable trace you are talking about is Stacktrace?

Comment: [DN]
CN=St.Department.146,OU=Mail Group,OU=STKGroup,DC=doublethink,DC=me

Comment: [StackTrace]
at Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.AdwsConnection.ThrowExceptionForFaultDetail(FaultDetail faultDetail, FaultException faultException)
   at Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.AdwsConnection.ThrowException(AdwsFault adwsFault, FaultException faultException)
   at Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.AdwsConnection.Modify(ADModifyRequest request)
   at Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADWebServiceStoreAccess.Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.IADSyncOperations.Modify(ADSessionHandle handle, ADModifyRequest request)

Comment: at Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADActiveObject.Update()
   at Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.ADSetCmdletBase`3.SetFromIdentity(O identity)
   at Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.ADSetCmdletBase`3.ADSetCmdletBaseProcessCSRoutine()
   at Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.CmdletSubroutinePipeline.Invoke()
   at Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.ADCmdletBase`1.ProcessRecord()

Comment: Does `Get-Adgroup $InternalDistro` return the group? If so then just do `Get-Adgroup $InternalDistro | Set-ADGroup -Replace @{msExchRequireAuthToSendTo=$true} -verbose`

Comment: $InternalDistro is this command.

$InternalDistro = (Get-ADGroup -filter 'name -eq "St.Department.146"')

Comment: Uh huh, so try the suggestion to pipe it into set-adgroup

Comment: The problem is the same as below :'-( 

Set-ADGroup -Identity "St.Department.146" -Replace @{"msExchRequireAuthToSendTo"=$true} -verbose

Comment: What if you use the SamAccountName of the group or its full DistinguishedName? The error you show complains about the `"St.Department.146"`

Comment: @Theo Thanks for the help.  The symptoms are the same even if you run the command.

Set-ADGroup -Identity "St.Department.146@doublethink.me" -Replace @{"msExchRequireAuthToSendTo"=$true} -verbose

Answer (score 0):

From the error

> An invalid dn syntax has been specified

It is clear that the error is occurring due to the Identity Parameter.

You could try the below  :

```
  Set-ADGroup -Identity "CN=St.Department.146,OU=Mail Group,OU=STKGroup,DC=doublethink,DC=me"  -Replace @{"msExchRequireAuthToSendTo"=$true} -verbose
```

If you want to avoid any typo, you can do a get group and subsequently pass it to the next step :

```
$InternalDistro = (Get-ADGroup -filter 'name -eq "St.Department.146"')
Write-Host $InternalDistro[0].DistinguishedName
Set-ADGroup -Identity $InternalDistro[0].DistinguishedName  -Replace @{"msExchRequireAuthToSendTo"=$true} -verbose
```

Ensure there is a output coming in the screen with required DN.

Comment: First Command 

Set-ADGroup : Directory object not found
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-ADGroup -Identity "CN=St.Department.146,OU=Mail Group,OU=STKGroup ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (CN=St.Departmen...ublethink,DC=me:ADGroup) [Set-ADGroup], ADIdentityNot
   FoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException,M
   icrosoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADGroup

Comment: Second Command

Set-ADGroup : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null. Provide a valid value for the
argument, and then try running the command again.
At line:1 char:23
+ Set-ADGroup -Identity $InternalDistro[0].DistinguishedName  -Replace  ...
+                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Set-ADGroup], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADGrou
   p

Comment: Weird ! the error indicates that the group is not existent in directory ! Are we sure we got the right DN or right group name?

Comment: I got it normally

DistinguishedName : CN=St.Department.146,OU=Mail Group,OU=STK Group,DC=doublethink,DC=me
GroupCategory     : Security
GroupScope        : Universal
Name              : St.Department.146
ObjectClass       : group
ObjectGUID        : a2c65e1f-d731-478f-aa86-2b31cbe175cf
SamAccountName    : St.Department.146

Answer (score 0):

To avoid errors in the `Identity` parameter, Try and use `Get-ADGroup` to find the group as object. If that succeeds, pipe the group object through to `Set-ADGroup`.
Get-ADGroup returns an object with default properties `DistinguishedName`, `GroupCategory`, `GroupScope`, `Name`, `ObjectClass`, `ObjectGUID`, `SamAccountName`, `SID`

```
# try and find the group with that name. 
# Use double-quotes around the filter and single-quotes around the name itself.
$groupName = 'St.Department.146'
# instead of property Name, you can also try property DisplayName here
$group = Get-ADGroup -Filter "Name -eq '$groupName'" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if ($group) {
    $group | Set-ADGroup -Replace @{msExchRequireAuthToSendTo = $true} -Verbose
}
else {
    Write-Warning "A group with name '$groupName' does not exist"
}
```

In this case, it could very well be the group has a different Name than its DisplayName. In the above code, if you see the warning message that the group does not exist, change
`-Filter "Name -eq '$groupName'"` into `-Filter "DisplayName -eq '$groupName'"` and try that.

Comment: @권양환 Well, then my friend you have a serious problem with that group.. It is always a bad idea to use dots and spaces in AD names and in a DN, these characters need to be escaped with a backslash. See what you get with `Get-ADGroup -Identity 'CN=St\.Department\.146,OU=Mail\ Group,OU=STK\ Group,DC=doublethink,DC=me'` or `Get-ADGroup -Identity ' a2c65e1f-d731-478f-aa86-2b31cbe175cf'`. If that too does not work, you may have to recreate that group, this time leave out the problematic characters..